# How to separate authorization logic from controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, authorization

Given the following code:

```
public class BackupsController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IApiContext context;
    private readonly IBackupService backupService;

    public BackupsController(IApiContext context, IBackupService backupService)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.backupService = backupService;
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage Get(Guid id)
    {
        if (id == Guid.Empty)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        IBackupView backup = backupService.Get(id);

        if (backup == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, String.Format("BackupId '{0}' not found.", id));
        }

        if (!IsAuthorizedForBackup(backup))
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, backup);
    }

    private bool IsAuthorizedForBackup(IBackupView backup)
    {
        if (context.Principal.IsInRole(MembershipRole.Admin))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (context.Principal.AllowDataSharing && backup.UserId == context.Principal.UserId)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (backup.UserId == context.Principal.UserId && backup.Device.Uuid == context.DeviceUuid)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Does it make sense to extract almost all of the method body into an authorization filter?  I don't see a way to do that without retrieving the backup twice.

**How would you go about separating the authorization concerns from the controller action?**

Answer (score 3):

In order to separate security logic from controller logic I prefer to use Http Headers to carry security tokens between browser and controller and check that header value in a custom `AuthorizeAttribute`

For example;

In `beforeSend` function of JQuery's ajax function set the security token (which is previously taken from the server, see below)

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('requestToken', model.requestToken);
}
```

Check the token in a custom `AuthorizeAttribute`

```
public class AuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var token = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["requestToken"];
        // Do the authorization based on token
    }
}
```

Decorate the controller, whose actions require authorization, with the custom `[Auth]` Attribute, like:

```
[Auth]
public class SomeController : ApiController
```

We can send new token back to client again using Http Headers

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Headers["requestToken"] = Guid.NewGuid();
```

And at client-side you can store it in success function of JQuery's ajax function for sending back in request

```
success: function (res, status, xhr) {
    model.requestToken = xhr.getResponseHeader('requestToken');
}
```

This may not handle your situation perfectly but main idea is carrying the (preferably encrypted) security data in Http Headers and dealing the security things in a custom `AuthorizeAttribute`

Comment: Hey Mehmet, thanks for taking the time to answer.  I am well aware of how to leverage custom AuthorizeAttributes.  I was more specifically interested in getting some feedback on whether or not it's possible to separate the authorization check from the controller action in my specific example.  Notice how the authorization check is dependent upon a service call given the parameter that is passed to the action.

Comment: I see. If you do not want to retrieve backup object twice, you can still extract auth logic into an AuthAttribute and if authorization passes, put the backup object into some dictionary (Session, HttpContext.Current.Items, CallContext or a custom one) that is accessible from controller. Then retrieve the same backup object from that dictionary. But this may reduce maintainability, anyone who writes code in controller should know that required backup object is somewhere in some global dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is technically possible. Say, you implement an action filter and have some logic in the overridden OnActionExecuted to set the status code to Forbidden. I have not done it this way and it is only a suggestion for you to explore the feasibility. OnActionExecuted runs after the action method and it can access backup.

Another better alternative is to use claims based identity and implement a sub-class of ClaimsAuthorizationManager. CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext) takes in both action claims and resource claims. Attributes related to back up can be passed along as resource claims.